# Is it possible to use a normal publisher in place of a TransformBroadcaster?

Tags: ros, publisher, learning-tf, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm just wondering whether a TransformBroadcaster does anything special that a normal publisher can't. Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199692/is-it-possible-to-use-a-normal-publisher-in-place-of-a-transformbroadcaster?/) by [nodge](https://answers.ros.org/users/21149/nodge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2014-12-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The TransformBroadcaster is a class which takes care of basic boilerplate conversions and a little bookkeeping. The source is here: https://github.com/ros/geometry_experimental/blob/indigo-devel/tf2_ros/include/tf2_ros/transform_broadcaster.h and https://github.com/ros/geometry_experimental/blob/indigo-devel/tf2_ros/src/transform_broadcaster.cpp

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0